# Est-ce qu'il existe des verbes à particule en Français ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, terminologie

Dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53913/31692) (en anglais), il est dit que le français ne possède pas de verbe à particule. ("..we don't have phrasal verbs..")

Ceci est confirmé par le site de [Office québécois de la langue française](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/26507027/verbe-a-particule), et par le manque de résultats pertinents dans mes recherches (la plupart étant des explications sur les verbes à particule en anglais)

Pourtant [wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_%C3%A0_particule) en cite quelques-uns :

- `courir sus`
- `mettre bas`
- `passer outre`
- `tomber sur`

Ces exemples semblent convenir à la définition de verbe à particule: `un mot composé constitué d'un verbe de base associé à un élément d'origine non verbale (la « particule ») qui en complète ou en modifie le sens`

- Est-ce que ce sont des verbes à particule ?
- Si oui, en existe-t-il
  d'autre en français ? (je pensais notamment à `compter sur` ?)
- Si non, qu'est-ce que c'est ?

Comment: En effet le terme « verbe à particule » n'est pas employé en grammaire française. On peut parfois tomber sur des sites en anglais (mais pas des livres de grammaire sérieux) qui parlent de *French phrasal verbs* qui donnent des listes de ce qu'on appelle en français des  « locutions verbales ».

Comment: Je pense que les exemples sont trop rares pour en faire une vraie catégorie plutôt qu'une curiosité. Personnellement je ne vois pas de réelle différence entre "*aller vers*" et "*tomber sur*", juste des verbes qui prennent une préposition. Le fait que le sens change parfois avec la préposition ne suffit pas à en faire une classe à part selon moi.

Comment: D'ailleurs, pour moi "*tomber sur*" n'est même pas à proprement parler un cas de verbe à particule, c'est juste un des sens de "tomber" qui de fait, n'a de sens que s'il est employé avec un complément, et donc une préposition. "*Mettre bas*" et "*passer outre*" sont de meilleurs exemples.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat oui - juste des verbes ordinaires, avec une préposition. En tout cas, c'est comme ça qu'on pense et comprend ces phrases. `courir sus` et `mettre bas` sont différents: la première expression n'est plus employée, la deuxième serait une "locution verbale" comme le dit @None, de même que `compter sur`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was prompted by a false information found on Wikipedia  (that may happen!) and the OP  has already found a correct answer from the [GDT](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/26507027/verbe-a-particule).  A question could be about the difference between *verbes à particule* and *verbes prépositionnels* but since French doesn't have *verbes à particule* it would be better asked on [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @None On devrait plutôt garder cette question, pour faire contre-poids à Wikipedia, justement. Sinon, l'information erronée de Wikipedia survivra, alors que le correctif ici disparaitra.

Comment: @Frank Wikipedia c'est collaboratif, ça peut être modifié, je suis certaine que beaucoup de participants à des sites de SE sont rédacteurs/correcteurs sur wikipedia. Je pense qu'il vaut mieux que ce soit fait par un linguiste (ce que je ne suis pas de profession). Wikipedia a un nombre de visites autrement plus considérable que FL ! Mais je maintiens qu'une question (tournée autrement)  aurait sa place sur [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @None merci pour l'explication concernant les locutions verbales, je ne connaissais pas ce terme. Concernant la question, je pense qu'elle a sa place ici : elle concerne la langue française (d'un point de vue linguistique, mais ça fait partie des [topics](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), elle est assez précise et une réponse existe (il suffit de regarder les deux premiers commentaires).

Comment: @AloisChristen Dans la mesure où il n'existe pas de verbes à particule en français on ne peut faire de réponse qu'en comparant avec d'autres langues, ce n'est donc pas spécifique au français. En français (et dans la majorité des langues latines je crois) il existe un verbe différent pour exprimer ce qu'exprime la particule (ex :  *hinaufgehen/go up* // monter/ *bajar* ; *hinuntergehen/go down* // descendre/ *subir*) etc.

Comment: [suite] Ce que je voulais dire dans mon premier commentaire c'est que c'est que je pense (et je ne suis pas la seule je sais) que traduire *phrasal verbs* par *locutions verbales* est une erreur, les deux concepts ne se recoupent pas entièrement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plutôt que de dire que "le français ne possède pas de verbe à particule", il est peut-être plus juste de dire "la notion de verbe à particule n'est pas pertinente en français".

En effet même si certaines constructions y ressemblent (comme "mettre bas" et "passer outre") ce sont plutôt des curiosités linguistiques qu'une catégorie importante des constructions verbales (comme ça l'est en anglais). Bref, dans le cadre de l'apprentissage du français il vaut mieux ne pas retenir cette notion car on va souvent s'y tromper.

Par exemple pour "compter sur" c'est un faux équivalent. On peut effectivement dire "je compte sur lui" pour "I count on him", mais on n'a pas vraiment besoin de cette particule:

> - Tu crois qu'elle tiendra parole ? (Do you think she will keep her word?)
> - J'y compte bien ! (I count on it!)